# bootstrap - jquery CDN breaks navbar mobile pulldown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I hope the title is good enough to understand, I had a hard time myself thinking how to describe this.

I have the following code on my site

**Navbar Bootstrap**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="/images/logo.png" style="max-width:100px; margin-top: -10px;"></a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/how-to/">How To</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <a href="/login/" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right">Sign In</a>
                    <a href="/create/" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right">Create Account</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Javascript/jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#loginForm").submit(function() {
    var churchcode = $('#churchcode').attr('value');
    var username = $('#username').attr('value');
    var password = $('#password').attr('value');
    var passwordagain = $('#passwordagain').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/church/includes/create.php?",
            // WRONG WAY
            data: "churchcode="+ churchcode+
            "&username="+ username+
            "&password="+ password+
            "&passwordagain="+ passwordagain,
            // RIGHT WAY
            data:({churchcode: churchcode,username: username, password: password, passwordagain: passwordagain}),
            success: function(data) {
                $('div.alert').fadeIn();
                $('div.alert').html(data);
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
function hide(obj) {
    var el = document.getElementById(obj);
    el.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I know that I am calling the jquery CND `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` twice in my javascript, but I did that to show you guys the two places that I am trying to place the line.

For whatever reason no matter where I place the `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` (top or bottom) it breaks the pulldown menu which is `<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">` option that appears when the site is being viewed on a mobile browser. Here is what the mobile (responsive) view looks like that I am talking about. When I click the menu it does not pull anything down.

[image: Navbar]

If I remove the jquery CDN call from the page then the pulldown works again. But of course I need jquery to work. Any Ideas?

I have placed this jquery CDN line in every possible location and no matter what it breaks the pulldown bootstrap.

Comment: Looks to me like you're including jQuery twice (once at the start of your snippet and once at the end).

Comment: I said that in my post, it was an example of the two places I am placing the line.

Comment: My mistake - confusing example though...

Comment: yeah I deleted the second one, I thought it might be confusing

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please either delete the question or post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it, it was a combination of needing at least 1.9.3 version of jquery as well as some old ajax code.

I switched from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and change from

```
data: "churchcode="+ churchcode+
    "&username="+ username+
    "&password="+ password+
    "&passwordagain="+ passwordagain,
```

to

```
data:({churchcode: churchcode,username: username, password: password, passwordagain: passwordagain}),
```

and changed from

```
var churchcode = $('#churchcode').attr('value');
var username = $('#username').attr('value');
var password = $('#password').attr('value');
var passwordagain = $('#passwordagain').attr('value');
```

to

```
var churchcode = $('#churchcode').val();
var username = $('#username').val();
var password = $('#password').val();
var passwordagain = $('#passwordagain').val();
```

and it works!

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend you to download the jquery onto your server for it is not lag when the outbound connection is slow.